# Oracle SQL: Create view where different columns names will be one new Value Column

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Hello I have the following setup:

```
DATE           HOUR    COLUMN_A     COLUMN_B    COLUMN_C     COLUMN_D
01.01.2017      1      VALUE_A      VALUE_B     VALUE_C      VALUE_D
```

and so on

What I want to have is something like this

```
DATE           HOUR     KIND           VALUE
01.01.2017      1       COLUMN_A       Value_A
01.01.2017      1       COLUMN_B       Value_B
01.01.2017      1       COLUMN_C       Value_C
01.01.2017      1       COLUMN_D       Value_D
```

Right now I make it with `UNION ALL` which will start to scan the table 4 times. Is there a more efficient way for this problem that I do not see?

Comment: see if this helps - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=conversion-of-columns-into-rows

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of Oracle supports lateral joins -- which are faster.  In some versions you can use `unpivot`, but I find that syntax overly specialized (the syntax is arcane and only useful for one thing).

You should get similar performance with a `cross join` and `case`:

```
select t.date, t.hour, c.kind,
       (case c.kind
            when 'column_a' then colum_a
            when 'column_b' then colum_b
            when 'column_c' then colum_c
            when 'column_d' then colum_d
        end) as value
from t cross join
     (select 'column_a' as kind from dual union all
      select 'column_b' as kind from dual union all
      select 'column_c' as kind from dual union all
      select 'column_d' as kind from dual
     ) c;
```